# Stop repositioning of web contents upon zoom in/out

Tags: html, css, web

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I'd like to make my contents on the web to stay put upon zoom in/out or window resize. At first, it was on the center but then I put `position:absolute` on the outermost div, it moved a little to the left and the images are disarranged and distorted on window resize, zoom/in and out.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="utf-8;" content="text/html" />



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: It's completely up to the browser to "zoom" content on your page. Don't worry about it. There's no "correct" answer, as there's no standard way for the browser to zoom content.

Comment: But the images are distorted when I zoom my browser. I put `position:absolute` to make the images stay put upon window resize and zoomed. But since I put that code, they're distorted. How can I force my images to stay on their places?

Comment: window resize and zoom are 2 very different things.

Comment: post css please, and jsfiddle

Comment: Oh no, not another website that has three `<html>` elements. Why do you people keep doing that?

Comment: The markup you've posted isn't the markup you've linked to. The markup you've linked to is *completely* invalid, with three opening `<html>` tags. Please fix your markup, and then (if the problem persists) ask another question. This one should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The way a browser is *supposed* to zoom is identical to applying a CSS `scale` transformation to the document.

However, for some reason, Chrome does not do this. Instead it appears to literally scale each element individually, causing fractional values to break layouts. There's nothing you can do to change this, unfortunately.